# Adding new column to dataframe using values of multiple columns and querying in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes like this:

| First | Second | Third | Fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 23423 | 12342 | 43214 |
| 23453 | 22342 | 23421 | 43214 |
| 23453 | NA | NA | NA |

| Code | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | A |
| 23453 | B |
| 23423 | Other |
| 12342 | A |

I would like to add a fifth column to the first data frame based on the codes in each row. Using the second dataframe, if all the codes in a row are Type A, I would like to insert "A" into the fifth column.

If all the codes in a row are Type B, I would like to insert "B" in the fifth column.

If all the codes in a row are Type "Other", I would like to insert "Other".

If there are codes that are both Type A and B, I would like to insert "Both".

If there are codes that are both Type A, B, or A and B and Other, I would like to insert A, B, or Both, respectively.

I would also like to ignore all the NAs in a row.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your fourth condition is not clear.  Perhaps this helps `df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_to = 'Code', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% left_join(df2) %>% filter(!is.na(Type)) %>% distinct(rn, Type) %>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(Fifth = case_when(all(Type == "B") ~ "B", all(Type == "Other") ~ "Other", all(c("A", "B") %in% Type) & n_distinct(Type) == 2  ~"Both", n_distinct(Type) >=2 ~ toString(Type))) %>% select(-rn) %>% bind_cols(df1, .)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit (probably over-)complicated. First join all columns with their respective code, then `unite` columns and remove `NA`. Then check for unique values with the aid of `map` and finally add the rule for "both".

```
library(tidyverse)

# add row to show whether rule "Both" works
df <- df %>% add_row(First = 12345, Second = 23453)

df %>%
  left_join(type_df, by = c("First" = "Code")) %>%
  left_join(type_df, by = c("Second" = "Code")) %>%
  left_join(type_df, by = c("Third" = "Code")) %>%
  left_join(type_df, by = c("Fourth" = "Code")) %>%
  tidyr::unite(contains("Type"), col = "type", na.rm = TRUE, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(type = stringr::str_split(type, ",") %>%
    map(., ~ unique(.x)) %>%
    map_chr(., ~ paste(.x, collapse = ", "))) %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(
    str_detect(type, "A") & str_detect(type, "B") ~ "Both",
    TRUE ~ type
  ))
```

**Output**:

```
  First Second Third Fourth     type
1 12345  23423 12342  43214 A, Other
2 23453  22342 23421  43214        B
3 23453     NA    NA     NA        B
4 12345  23453    NA     NA     Both
```

**Data**:

```
df <- read.table(text = "First  Second  Third   Fourth
12345   23423   12342   43214
23453   22342   23421   43214
23453   NA  NA  NA", h=T)

type_df <- read.table(text = "Code  Type
12345   A
23453   B
23423   Other
12342   A", h = T)
```